# How to get the message_id of received messages with Telethon?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telethon

I take [replier.py](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/master/telethon_examples/replier.py) as base code from official Telethon examples.
I want to get message id each time I receive a message.

```py
...
@events.register(events.NewMessage)
async def handler(event):
    if not event.out:
        print(f'received message_id = {event.message_id()}')
    client = event.client

with client:
    client.add_event_handler(handler)
    client.run_until_disconnected()
```

```sh
>>> ... AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'message_id'
```

I've tried several variants with no success.
How to do it properly?

Answer (score 6):

It's an attribute, and you use the dot operator to access it:

```
@events.register(events.NewMessage)
async def handler(event):
    message_id = event.id
    print(message_id)
```

See also [Telethon's FAQ on that topic](https://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick-references/faq.html#how-do-i-access-a-field).